# continuity of L-S integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

$A_t$ is a BV right continuous function on $[0,a]$.

$f(t)$ is a borel measurable function on $[0,a]$ which satisfy:
$$\int_0^a|f(s)|\,|dA_s|<\infty$$

I want to show
$$g(t):=\int_0^tf(s)\,dA_s$$
is right continuous on $[0,a]$.

---

$$|g(t+h)-g(t)|=|\int_t^{t+h}f(s)\,dA_s|\le\int_0^a1_{(t,t+h]}(s)|f(s)|\,|dA_s|$$

then by DCT,we get the conclusion.

My question is we can also get the LEFT continuity of $g$ by the same procedure,but in general this conclusion is false .Moreover,I didn't use the right continuity of $A$.I think the right continuity of $A$ is only used to construct the L-S measure,right?

Comment: For left-continuity, your integrand would be $1_{(t-h,t]}(s)\cdot \lvert f(s)\rvert$. Does that converge to $0$ (almost everywhere)?

Comment: @DanielFischer,oh it is$ |f(t)|$, and I get $\Delta g(t)=f(t)\Delta A(t)$